# Spring Boot 2 clustering with one database instance

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm new to the Spring Eco System and I was wondering, if there is anything that should be done if you wanna scale the application layer horizontally and preserve only one database instance (in this case Postgresql).

Speaking of, should I worry about inconsistency because of a default second or third level cache in the applications or any other things?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your setup I could see 2 things

1. You want to scale horizontally at application level but with just single DB. Which might turn out to be the Single Point of Failure. You can run your DB in a cluster as well.
2. Multiple instances connected to the same Database. So there may be a case where Multiple reads at the same time will not be a problem but multiple writes to the same table work differently so watch out for that.

You can read more about [Postgresql blocking](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2018/02/15/when-postgresql-blocks/) here.

> Regarding your concern on the inconsistency

There may be some inconsistency at some point of time but its effect would not be noticeable, just add few ms overheads.

**Note:**

You haven't mentioned how are you planning to scale at application level generait's its done using LoadBalancer (eg: Nginx)